# Linker can not find __imp_clock and __imp_time64 when building a sample of GTSAM

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, linker, gtsam

I build [GTSAM](https://gtsam.org/) in Windows and now I am trying to build a sample application with it.

The sample application is very simple (it is part of GTSAM) but when I run it, I am getting this linker error:

```
Severity    Code    Description                                                                 Project  File   Line    Suppression State
Error       LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_clock referenced in function gk_CPUSeconds example  D:\MyData\SourceCode\gtsam_win\cmake\example_cmake_find_gtsam\build\metis-gtsamDebug.lib(timers.obj)
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description                                                             Project     File                                                                                                    Line    Suppression State
Error       LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__time64 referenced in function time    example     D:\MyData\SourceCode\gtsam_win\cmake\example_cmake_find_gtsam\build\metis-gtsamDebug.lib(timers.obj)    1
```

a search showed me that these two functions are part of MSVC libraries and they should in linked to the system.

How can I fix the issue?

It seems that the problem is mismatch between the setting during library build and application build, but I can not find any linker setting different. Where to look for any such difference?

Comment: Maybe you are building the application with Multi-threaded runtime (/MT) instead of  Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)? (C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library) `__imp_` prefix means the library is built with DLL runtime.

Comment: @dewaffled That solved my problem. The key message was that __imp) prefioc means that library is build with DLL. The reason is that I had error for /MT and /MD mismatch which I fixed, so I thought This can not be problem. This message gave me the clue I should look at it again and I found that in GTSAM, there is an error that GTSAM and metis-gtsam uses different setting when creating libraries.  When I got error message, and I fixed it, it worked well with gtsam, but gtsam-metis has different setting and still created with /md. Interestingly, No linker error complaining about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__imp_` prefix in unresolved external runtime library symbol from the linked library means the library was built with DLL runtime (`/MD` in `C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`).

If you build the application with static runtime (`/MT`) the symbols from the DLL runtime will be unresolved. Runtime settings should be the same for all compilation units.